# Having trouble with variables and if/elif/else in Python 2.7.8

Tags: python, if-statement

I am new to Python, so I'm trying to write a simple email blast application. When I compile, I get an "invalid syntax error on line 4" message.

Here is my code:

```
import easygui as gui
import smtplib
choice = gui.buttonbox(msg = 'Who is your email provider?', title = 'Mailblaster', choices =     ("Gmail", "Yahoo", "AOL", "iCloud","Hotmail/Outlook.com",)
if choice == 'Gmail'
 smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("imap.gmail.com",587)
elif choice =='Yahoo'
 smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("imap.mail.yahoo.com",465)
elif choice == 'AOL'
 smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("imap.aol.com",587)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a colon after `if`, `else` and `elif`, like this:

```
if choice == 'Gmail':
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("imap.gmail.com",587)
```

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I tried and got the same error.

Comment: @user3649933 You're also missing a closing parenthesis on line 3